# SHRINK FILE works with SA but not as a normal user

Tags: sql-server, shrink, sql-server-express

My problem is that when I try to shrink the Log it works when I am logged in as SA but when I log in as a "normal" USER it does not shrink the log. (SQL Express 2008r2)

I have tried to find a answer to my problem but I cant. So please help me! =)

Answer (score 8):

The *last* thing you want is allowing a normal user to run DBCC SHRINKxxx

This should be reserved for highly privileged users to run in a few rare circumstances. This should not be a regular or normal operation.

Permissions for both [DBCC SHRINKDATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488.aspx) and [DBCC SHRINKFILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx) are

> Requires membership in the sysadmin fixed server role or the db_owner fixed database role.

If you really want to run this because you know better, then use a stored proc with [EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx)

```
CREATE PROC dbo.IKnowBetter
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER -- escalates to db_owner in dbo schema
AS
DBCC SHRINKFILE (1);
DBCC SHRINKFILE (2);
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.IKnowBetter TO OikUser;
```

Comment: It's a backup program that runs the script and it takes the USER info from a .ini-file for the system I want to take the backup on. Those USERS are allready set do db_owners.

Comment: @user1065878: check they really are db_owner and you're in the correct database. Otherwise, MSDN must *wrong* and needs corrected via MS Connect...

Comment: Yes they really are members of the db_owner role so I will post on MS Connect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1065878: don't embarrass yourself. I have shrunk files with db_owner only *without* sysadmin so MSDN is *correct*. I'd suggest you read the rest of my comment, which states "in the correct database". You are probably trying to shrink the wrong DB files or the user isn't the one you expect.

Comment: Hmm okey. I belive I have to do embrass myself because I can't find a solution and I have tested on several systems. Anyway I will continue to try to find a solution..

Comment: @user1065878: **HAVE YOU CHECKED THE DATABASE CONTEXT**

Comment: Expanding slightly on gbn's answer: one should check not just the server-level *login*, but also the database-level *user*.  Under the user's properties, check General | Database role membership, scroll down, and ensure db_owner is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Regular user have no permissions to do maintenance tasks. If you want the regular user to perform these tasks - add him to fixed server role **sysadmin** or make him a **db_owner** of the DB

For details see here: [DBCC SHRINKFILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189493.aspx)

Comment: Can you show where you got those permissions from?

Comment: @gbn Oops! Fixed.

Comment: The User is allready set to db_owner. If I do the same on a 2005 express i does work

Comment: @user1065878: in the correct database? db_owner is *not* a normal user

Comment: Hmm I maby used the wrong word "normal". The thing is that it's a program running the script. And it takes the SQL user information from a .ini-file and the user in there is set to a db_owner. Maybe it doesent make sense but that is how it works right now =).